# Present Objective-C UIViewController from Swift UI Button

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and introducing SwiftUI in an existing Objective-C project. I am initializing SwiftUI View (`struct contentView: View`) using `UIHostingController` in `UIViewController(SwiftViewControllerUsedToPresentSwiftUI)`
like so:

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController.init(rootView: contentView)
```

This part works fine.
I want to call an existing `UIViewController` which has an associated xib file in project. I want to present this `UIViewController` on a button press/click.
something like:

```
let myExistingUIViewController = MyExistingUIViewController(nibName: "MyExistingUIViewController", bundle: nil)
myExistingUIViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
present(myExistingUIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I understand I can present any `UIViewController` only from another `UIViewController`. Not sure if I should write one just to call the existing `UIViewController`. I tried to use the one which I used to host this SwiftUI but gives me error:

> [Presentation] Attempt to present <MyExistingUIViewController: 0x7f7a67827c00> on <SwiftViewControllerUsedToPresentSwiftUI: 0x7f7a64720da0> (from <SwiftViewControllerUsedToPresentSwiftUI: 0x7f7a64720da0>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.

As per @Allan suggestion added UIViewControllerRepresentable Following is the code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MyExistingUIViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyExistingUIViewController {
        let mySwiftUIView = MyExistingUIViewController(nibName: "MyExistingView", bundle: nil)
             return mySwiftUIView
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyExistingUIViewController, context: Context) {
            //code
        }
}
```

In button press action - it is called as follows ...

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingWrapperView){
                MyExistingUIViewControllerWrapper()
```

Now the issue remains to display it as formsheet and not sheet as the existing xib with this existing ViewController is a formsheet.

The way I worked around the formsheet issue is as follows -

The way the screens appear in the app -

Objective C View Controller to Swift UI to Objective C form sheet.

Did Objective C (FirstObjCViewControoler) to Swift UI (SwiftUIContentView) by using UIHostingController.

Now from Swift UI (SwiftUIContentView) to MyExistingUIViewController in the form of formsheet was achieved as follows -

From FirstObjCViewController passed a 2 handlers to SwiftUIContentView. One can be used to close this SwiftUIView and other can be used to close the SwiftUIView and can do additional work to open MyExistingUIViewController from FirstObjCViewControoler .

Here is the code where SiftUIView is created by Obj C UIViewController -

```
 UIViewController *newSwiftUIView = [NewSwiftUIView makeNewSwiftUIView WithSomeFirstArg:someFirstArg closeHandler:^{
                        [[self presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                    }
                   closeAndOpenMyExistingUIViewControllerHandler:^{
                        [[self presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        [self OpenMyExistingUIViewController]; // This can be defined in FirstObjCViewController to open FormSheet
                    }];
```

Here is how makeNewSwiftUIView is written to receive the handlers-

```
@objc static func makeNewSwiftUIView( someFirstArg:NSArray, closeHandler : @escaping (() -> Void), closeAndOpenMyExistingUIViewControllerHandler : @escaping (() -> Void)) -> UIViewController
```

This works beautifully. It is very clean and came to my mind when I realized how involved it is to create formsheet UIViewController from SwiftUI.

I have spend almost 1.5 days to reach here, hopefully this will save someone else's time.

Comment: if you expect people to invest time reading and answering your question, consider investing into formatting it properly. Impossible to read as it is.

Comment: @HangarRash will be careful next time.

Comment: I believe you just replied to the wrong person.

Comment: Talking about me? @HangarRash because I gave your the exact answer. MyExistingUIViewController have to be transformed into a SwiftUIViewController, by making it conforms to UIViewControllerRepresentable. Then you should present this into your SwiftUI Hierarquy simples but putting .sheet($isPresented) { MyExistingUIViewController()) (You will never call "present" from the SwiftUI World... this is imperative and SwiftUI is declarative) Maybe, if you are in doubt continue using just UIKit without comes and goes.

Comment: @AllanGarcia No, I'm not talking about you and it's not my question. Why is everyone replying to me? All I did is edit the question. I didn't post it. user1664018 posted the question.  khjfquantumjj posted a comment. The OP then mistakenly replied to me as if I had posted the comment. So I replied (to the OP) that they replied to the wrong person. Then Allan Garcia thought it was my question and mistakenly replied to me. So much confusion.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Sometimes SO is read with fast paced work in hand. Confusion and lack of clarity is very common.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call an UIViewController function from SwiftUI (on Button action for instance) you have to make your UIViewController class UIViewControllerRepresentable conforming.

This doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

From this instance of this class you could present a view ViewController normally.

Comment: Thank you @Allan, I created UIViewControllerRepresentable and invoke it with .sheet too. I need a formsheet view and not sheet as I mentioned in my post too. Is there any way this can show up as formsheet?

Comment: Not in my knowledge that there is a presentation of .formsheet into the SwiftUI yet. Most similar will be a .fullScreeCover modifier and you "simulate" a formsheet inside using ```List {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Name", text: $text)
                    }
                }
            }.formStyle(.grouped) ``` (sorry, no formatting into the comments)